# how to disable Select List and Date Picker for user but it should able to update through Dynamic Action

Tags: datepicker, oracle-apex, selectlistitem

in oracle apex created a simple Form (not IG) and need to disable/read only a Select List and a Date Picker page items for users when there is data, but i can update its value through Dynamic Action... is it possible? if yes, how to? please help.

Comment: If it is disabled or read only - do you need it to be a select list and date picker ? If a user cannot change the value, why not just make them both "display only" page items ? That will be less confusing to the user.

Comment: thanks @KoenLostrie. will Display only allow me to update values through DA?

Comment: Yes and you need "send on page submit" set to Yes so it is saved in session state

Comment: thanks @KoenLostrie, will check it and confirm.